# C++ Stack Template SIGTRAP Error

Tags: c++, class, templates, stack

Just started learning about stack templates and ran into an issue while working on the push function whenever I try to free up memory to resize. The function works fine all the way up until it has reached maximum capacity, and then immediately goes into a series of error messages not really picked up by my debugger. 
Here's the header file with the function causing the error, plus the function it calls.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>

class MyStack
{
  private:
  T* data;
  int topVal;
  int capacity;

  public:
  MyStack()
  {
    capacity = 10;
    topVal = 0;
    data = new T[capacity];
  }

  ~MyStack()
  {
    delete [] data;
    data = 0;
  }
  void push(T);
  T pop();
  T top();
  bool isFull();
  bool isEmpty();
  string toString();
};

template <class T>
void MyStack<T>::push(T value)
{
  if(!isFull())
  {
    data[++topVal] = value;
  }
  else
  {
    capacity *= 2;
    T* holdPtr = new T[capacity];
    for(int i = 0; i <= topVal; ++i)
      holdPtr[i] = data[i];
    delete [] data;                 //This is where the error is occurring
    data = holdPtr;
    data[++topVal] = value;
  }
}


template <class T>
bool MyStack<T>::isFull()
{
  if(topVal < capacity)
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Problem solved! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You created `data` with `new []`. You should use `delete []` to free it.

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't seem to fix the problem I'm having, but, still, thank you for pointing that out to me!

Comment: `push()`'s closing brace is missing, but since your code obviously compiled I'm assuming it's a typo when posting here.

Comment: @T.C. Thank you! Yeah, it's just a typo. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two (related) problems:

1) With an empty stack, `topval == 0`. But your `push` puts the element in `data[++topVal]` - i.e., `data[1]`. `data[0]` is never used.

2) When `topval == 9` and `capacity == 10`, your `isFull()` returns `false` and your `push` tries to stores the value in `data[10]`, which is out-of-bounds and corrupts memory.

Also, your `push` should either take `value` by `const` reference or (if you are using C++11) use `std::move`.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem I was having! I appreciate all your help and advice.